# Flutter Mobile App Automation using Appium and Python widget click event could not perform in flutter dialog

Tags: python, flutter, appium

Issue is:
We could not find the widget which is in the currently opened dialog box in flutter mobile App and automation flow is not going forward.

However In the login screen we could find the input fields like email, password, and can perform the click event on the Login button.

```
from appium import webdriver
import time
from appium_flutter_finder import FlutterFinder, FlutterElement

desired_cap = {
    "deviceName": "27151JEGR",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "13",
    "automationName": "Flutter",
    "autoAcceptAlerts": "true",
    "app": "apk path"
}
server = "server IP"

print("launch app")
driver = webdriver.Remote(server, desired_cap)
print("app launched")
time.sleep(8)

FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("userId")).click()
FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("userId")).send_keys("email address")
time.sleep(1)

FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("password")).click()
FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("password")).send_keys("password text")
time.sleep(1)

FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("login_button")).click()
print("tapped on login button")
time.sleep(10)

#Below line is to perform the click on Home button (Which is in the dialog) which is not working and testing controller gets stopped from here.
#We have tried by text, and key.
FlutterElement(driver, FlutterFinder().by_value_key("home_login_biometric")).click()
print("tapped on home button")
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look to [appium-flutter-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-flutter-driver/blob/main/README.md) docs

```
    driver.elementSendKeys(find.byType('TextField'), 'I can enter text') (no focus required)
    driver.elementClick(find.byType('TextField'));
    driver.execute('flutter:enterText', 'I can enter text') (focus required by tap/click first)
```